# Where can I find the documentation for configuring the logging settings for Microsoft extension logging?

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, .net-core

Everywhere you can find example on with the default settings

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to know if there is more than that, for exmple if i can customize the format of the message like in NLOG layout attribute.

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" layout="${date:format=yyyyMMddHHmmss} ${message}" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'Microsoft extension logging'?

Comment: The OP probably refers to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` namespace & package ([GitHub project page](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging)). Their [sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/samples/SampleApp/logging.json) looks very similar to the OP's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer might not be entirely accurate, since I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET Core Logging. The following is based on some research and looking at source code and examples.

A quick look at the source code of the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` NuGet package (whose source code can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging)) reveals that the settings you're showing might be specific to the `ConsoleLogger`, which doesn't recognize any other settings. See for yourself by looking at the source files [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console), especially [the file `ConfigurationConsoleLoggerSettings.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/ConfigurationConsoleLoggerSettings.cs) where you'll find which configuration sections are accessed.

Different loggers might take completely different approaches to read their configuration. For example, NLog can be configured with an XML file. If you want to use NLog, you need to register the appropriate log provider with ASP.NET Core. You want the [NLog provider](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging). There's an [example project on that project page](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/tree/master/examples/aspnet-core-example/src/aspnet-core-example) that demonstrates its basic use:

```
// add the NuGet package `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` as a project dependency,
// which makes these namespaces available: 
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Web;

// your ASP.NET Core startup / configuration class:
partial class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        …
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        app.AddNLogWeb();
        …
    }
}
```

Then [configure NLog through the `NLog.config` XML file](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file).

Comment: Thank for the answer. I'm used to NLog (that I think is awesome) but as I'm working on a brand new project with ASP net core I wanted to give a try to what Microsoft propose. To be honest I didnt get the idea of NLOG provider: if I'm already using NLOG why would I use Microsoft logging too?!? I'd like to look at the source code too but I would expect that at least for something like there could be a simple document (again NLog docet..)

Comment: @PaoloV: I don't know for sure, .NET Core is very new to me, too. But I suspect the providers' purpose is to fully integrate any logging solution and ASP.NET Core. That is, ASP.NET Core might then also output *its* log messages using *your* chosen logging library. The provider is the bridge. In the full .NET Framework, such things could be done via `Web.config`'s `<system.diagnostics>` section, but now that `Web.config` is essentially gone (from the application's perspective), a new configuration mechanism is required (namely, registering a library in `Startup`).